# Who (authorization servers) support "Resource Ownder Password Credential" flow?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

It may not be good to ask this question here, but even after doing a lot investigation I did not found which public api supports OAuth 2.0's "Resource Ownder Password Credential" flow.

We are building Generic REST client and want to know if there is real life example for this flow.

Thanks,
Rahul